# Kendo UI grid custom filter using data-binding on checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Here's what I want to achieve in a nutshell:

The ability to add a custom filter using checkboxes that when checked applies a custom filter value to the Kendo UI grid other than true or false.

Here's my custom filter template:

```
<div id="orderNumberFilterTemplate">
    <input type="hidden" data-bind="value:logic" value="or" />
        <label for="customerOrders" title="Show only orders going directly to the customer.">
            <input type="checkbox" class="k-checkbox" id="customerOrders" data-bind="checked:filters[1].value" name="orderTypes" value="6" />Direct to customer
        </label><br />
        <label for="galleryOrders" title="Show only orders going back to the store.">
            <input type="checkbox" class="k-checkbox" id="storeOrders" data-bind="checked:filters[2].value" name="orderTypes" value="5" />Direct to store
        </label><br />
        <label for="stockOrders" title="Show only restocking orders.">
            <input type="checkbox" class="k-checkbox" id="stockOrders" data-bind="checked:filters[3].value" name="orderTypes" value="3" />Stock orders
        </label><br />
</div>
```

Here is my custom filter function:

```
function orderNumberFilter(element) {           
        element.after('<div>' + $('#orderNumberFilterTemplate').html() + '</div>');
};
```

And here is my application of the filter function to the grid:

```
columns: [
    { 
        field: 'orderNumber', 
        title: 'Order Number', 
        filterable: {
            ui: orderNumberFilter,
        }
    }
]
```

What I am after here is that when someone ticks a checkbox, I want the filters to be updated with { field: 'myfield', operator: 'startswith', value: 6 } but being a checkbox, it is automatically updating them with value: true when checked.  Is there any way to create a custom filter than specifies values rather than a checkbox true or false to the filter.

Also, is it possible to apply a binding attribute that specifies what kind of operator is used, as I'd really like to have the standard textbox filter from kendo work as normal but also have these checkboxes below use a different operator than the one applied to the textbox.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, check boxes values are `true` or `false` but you can add some extra information to them adding `data-xyz` attribute and then ask for `xyz`.

Example:

```
<label for="customerOrders" title="Show only orders going directly to the customer.">
    <input type="checkbox" class="k-checkbox" id="customerOrders" data-bind="checked:filters[1].value" name="orderTypes" data-value="6" />
    Direct to customer
</label>
```

I've replaced your `value` by a `data-value`. Now, I can do:

```
function orderNumberFilter(element) {           
    var value = $(element).data("value");
    ...
};
```

Example here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/cY9Wg/

Comment: The question is also about applying it as a Kendo UI grid filter which your answer, although helpful - don't get me wrong, does not help with and I need the two working.  If I were to extract the value out as you have done, there are ways I am aware of to apply the filter to the grid.  If I do as you suggest in the fiddle, then it would apply the filter as soon as you tick the box, which isn't an option, I need it to work seamlessly with the grid, i.e. only applies when the user clicks the apply button on the filter popup.

Comment: If I hook into the click event on the apply button and get all the filters and send them to the datasource, one of two things happen: if another column has a standard Kendo placed filter with an actual value on it, then kendo resends a filter command to the datasource - without my filters applied after the one I send, so two requests are made and the grid ends up only applying the standard ones.

Comment: If no other kendo standard filters have a value then only the one request - the one I apply with the custom filters is sent, which is great but doesn't work correctly as soon as you use a standard filter :(

Comment: Ideally, I would like it to work like the standard Kendo grid filters work, but I don't know enough about them or MVVM to get the binding to work and get Kendo to recognise that something has changed in this filter popup's filters.  I expect that MVVM has a flag or something within the bound filter with the input elements to know when they have been changed so that it knows to re-apply the filters.

Comment: I'm pretty lost on what you are (finally) trying to achieve. I've tried to solve the question of the _values_ in the checkboxes but seems that your problem is build a filter (incrementally compatible with other filters) and selectable by checkboxes in a Grid. Correct?